# How do I say "nice playing with you"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

Is it right to say "It was nice playing with you in the same team" or "It was nice playing together in the same team"?

Comment: Both are correct, and to all intents and purposes identical in meaning.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - Would you say "_in_ the same team"? Here in the US, we'd say "_on_ the same team". In any case, I have a hunch the OP might appreciate a pointer to [ell.se].

Comment: Both sound very formal.

Comment: @J.R. Yes, British English uses *in* far more often than AmE. "I play in a team; They have a shop in the High Street" (although the AmE *on* is becoming more common for that last one).

Comment: @AndrewLeach - We don't have any High Streets in the U.S.

Comment: "I've enjoyed" is probably better than "It's was nice".

Comment: @aparente001 You've never visited Columbus, OH, then  ;-)

Comment: @JohnFeltz - Okay, maybe you have a High Street, but do you have a ***shop*** on/in your High Street?

Comment: @aparente001 [Here's one](http://www.hcpcme.org/ellsworth/Sidewalks/south.html), complete with a [business district](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellsworth,_Maine), it would seem. :)

Comment: @Lawrence - If you can quote the Chamber of Commerce talking about the *shops* on/in their High Street, then you'll have found the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: @aparente001 Challenge accepted :) . (1) The [Ellsworth Chamber of Commerce](https://www.ellsworthchamber.org/events/downtown-holiday-marketplace/) is situated on High Street. (2) If you'll accept a *Mall* as a synonym for *shop*: ["Maine Coast **Mall** 225 High St ... retail, **shop**ping"](https://www.ellsworthchamber.org/members/?category=Malls); and (3) if you don't: ["Barber **Shops** & Beauty Salons ... 107 High Street"](https://www.ellsworthchamber.org/members/turning-heads/). (With due apologies to the OP for the sidetrack.)

Answer (score 1):

The standard phrase to express camaraderie after a fun game in sports is **"Good game!"**  You can say it to someone from either side.

With a teammate, you could make it more friendly and enthusiastic:

> Great game, man!  *(And then you can add some specific positive feedback, such as, if you're talking to a soccer goalie, for example, "That was an incredible save you made in the second quarter!")*